# Usability of /usr/share today

Tags: architecture, fhs

How is separating architecture dependent static data from architecture independent static data useful today?

I imagine it could theoretically be useful in multi-architecture networks with a network-mounted `/usr/share`. But then, wouldn't that slow things down a lot in comparison to having `/usr/share` on a local hard-drive (HD space is cheap today)? Or is it used in virtualized environments where a network shared `/usr/share` is effectively local? Are multi-architecture networks still a thing today?

Answer (score 2):

If you develop some software (e.g. in C++) and want to test it both on 64 bits and 32 bits Linux systems you might install a `chroot`-ed 32 bits distribution on a 64 bits desktop, and then it could make sense to share the `/usr/share`

But I agree with you, [thin clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client) are not very useful today (much less than 10 or 20 years ago).

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for separating architecture independent files from architecture dependent is so they do not need to be duplicated across architectures. This is something that multi-arch distributions / operating systems (like Debian) do to reduce space usage in their archives.